# Getting Hoptoad to work in a staging environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, staging, hoptoad

I have an action which causes an exception in my staging environment, but instead of sending the notification to hoptoad (which it should, the hoptoad test rake task works...), it shows me the standard rails stacktrace page like it does in development.

My staging environment is essentially a copy of my production environment with the only difference being the rails environment being set through passenger.

What could be the cause of this?  Where should I be looking?  I haven't confirmed that production does the same thing as we don't yet have a proper production environment set up, but I assume it would also act the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your staging instance is running in the correct environment?  Have you tried outputting Rails.env somewhere in your views just to make sure?

I only ask because you mentioned seeing a stack trace page, which shouldn't happen in a production environment unless you're making the requests locally, or you have config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local set to true in your environment config.

Comment: I forgot to mark this as the right answer.  It turns out I'm infact an idiot.  Go me!